# Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда люди говорят, они не думают – они знают.

Comment: Очень спорно по сути.

Answer (score 2):

Да, тире необходимо.

Comment: Ничего спорного.Без тире получилось бы интонация перечисления.